# Is Ganesha created based on Gautama Buddha?

Tags: ganesha, other-religions, buddhism

Is Ganesha created based on Gautama Buddha? I have read in many articles from several social platforms that the concept of Ganesha is derived from Buddhism.

Various names such as *vighnaharta* and *dukhharta* are taken from the principles of Buddhism, not sure about the authenticity of such articles, just curious if someone could shed some light on this.

Comment: @rajiv What?!  Nope.

Comment: Gautam buddha was born in 6th century B.C. The question which you are asking is suggesting that Ganpati was born after that. I don't think so. you can refer https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gautama_Buddha.

Comment: Can you link to the articles you're referring to?

Comment: Gaṇapati has been referenced even in the Rigvēda that Gautama Buddha likely studied when he was young. *Various names such as vighnaharta and dukhharta are taken from the principles of Buddhism* what does that even mean?